# Why my Rigidbody2D doesn't want to jump normaly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make character move with Rigidbody2D.MovePosition but it works only with horizontal movement.

I expected normal realistic jumps but it jumps randomly when I move character and doesn't jump with space button.

Also my wall jumps doesn't work.

Expected that the character will jump up and goes horizontaly to opposite wall. It does, but with VERY SMALL power.

I'm using Unity 2019.4.16f

```
using UnityEngine;

public class D2Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
public byte moveSpeed;
public byte plusJumpCount;
public float jumpStrength;
public byte wallJumpStrenght;
public bool isGrounded = false;
byte origJumpCount;
bool isWallL;
bool isWallR;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update(){
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, 0f);
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (plusJumpCount > 0 || isGrounded == true)){
        velocity.y = jumpStrength;
        plusJumpCount -= 1;
    }
    
    if(isGrounded == true){
        velocity.y = 0;
        plusJumpCount = origJumpCount;
    } else {
        velocity.y -= 10 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
        rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime * 2);
    } else {
        rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other){
    if(other.collider.tag == "Wall_L"){
        isWallL = true;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(wallJumpStrenght, jumpStrength / 2), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
    
    if(other.collider.tag == "Wall_R"){
        isWallR = true;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-wallJumpStrenght, jumpStrength / 2), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other){
    isWallL = false;
    isWallR = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why you are experiencing those bugs with this code, but there is some unusual stuff happening. Maybe try

- use the built in gravity. You can set the gravity in the rigidbody component.
- decide between jumping with rb.MovePosition or rb.addForce
- keep your code simple --> isWallL and isWallR are not really used, avoid duplicate code
- do physics related stuff inside FixedUpdate()
- avoid magic numbers (use const)

You will have less bugs with better written code!

Also maybe consider setting rb.velocity directly.

Answer (score 0):

Pikramag Channel, did you add related Component for collision2D, such as Rigidbody2D and boxcollision?
Only I see your editor code, I am not sure for getting errors.

Comment: Hi! This is more a comment not an answer to the question.  Two liners are usually not detailed enough for answers as the original posters might not understand them.

Comment: what do you mean "related"? i have 2 collider, 1 in children, 1 with RB2D. collider in children is for ground detection and it works with collision. collider in RB2D object is main one